# Is it possible to use macros created on system's ms-office into another system?

Tags: excel

I'm wondering, if its possible to use macros (PERSONAL.XLSB) file created on one system on other system by just coping the same on XLSTART Folder. I have created macros in office 2007 and wanna run these macros on my users system. For security stuff i have changed the security settings on my users ms-office to "low"/"allow all macros" options depending upon the respective office version.

Waiting for excel experts valuable comments and suggestions.

Any help will highly be appreciated.

mrana....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically its simple, just copy & paste your macros file in the above mentioned folder and then those will be available at your excel sheets.

One more method you guys could use just record a macro and select save in as "This workbook" as a option and then save that sheet as "macros enabled spread sheet" and share that where you want to.

Let me if i'm not clear to you guys..

mrana....